# Product Offering In Auto Renewable Subscription

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am having auto renewable subscription in my app.
on purchase I am calculating expire date and storing it in NSUserDefaults.
i have books as product which i am offering on monthly basis on every 1st day of the month.
my question is how should i offer products on subscription bases
for example if user buy subscription after 1st his expire date will not be 1st of the month and he will receive 2 product,
one for subscription buy month and one for expire date month if he subscribe for one month.
while he should get only one. so which one it should be, first one or the second one.
in case of first one,second product will be  unaccessible to the user for some duration.
in case of second one instantaneously user won't get anything.

in case providing book at the time of user subscribe.
if user subscribe for 1 year on 31-01-2012 he will receive 12 book from 01-01-2012 to 01-12-12 and one more book for month 01-01-2013 since his subscription will expire on 30-01-2013.
in case we only provide 12 book, book of month 01-01-2013 will be unaccessible to user until his subscription expire.since there are many app already in appStore which handling this problem.please explain me what to do.

can any one suggest me the way to do this
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear, if you provide book just for a month and than it's not unavailable anymore, or you just provide a new book everymonth?

If second, you should just provide him a new book at the next month's first day. And at the beggining of next month check,if he paid.

Comment: once user subscribe and product comes under his subscription it will be available to user forever. thanks for replay@Nikita Pestrov